# how to change floor sprite in unreal engine

Tags: sprites, unreal-4, unreal

I have started a 2D side scrolling game in Unreal Engine from the menu when you start a new game. The basic environment loads up and it works but I don't know how to change the floor sprites and player sprites. Please Help.

Comment: This seems like something that would be covered in very basic beginner tutorials, and doesn't really require 1-on-1 expert Q&A. Have you tried working through a few Unreal tutorials to get oriented with the main features of the tool?

Comment: @DMGregory I have but unfortunately I couldn't find any unreal tutorials with changing sprites in them if you could find any that would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Paper2D sprite is simply a plane with a material. Have you tried changing the material on your sprites?

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Paper2D/Sprites/